# How to trace at runtime the symbols of loaded shared library?

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-library, gdb, ltrace

I want to be able to know what are the symbols that are used from a certain shared library at runtime.
I use `gdb` and I set the `solib-search-path` to the user defined shared library. I am not sure if there is another way with `ltrace`

Comment: `ltrace -c -l 'yoursharedlib.so*' yourprogram args...` will list all the functions called by yourprogram in that shared library. It gives other info, too, so you may need to filter the output with `awk`. It won't list non-function symbols such as variables. Is that what you need?